# viewModel by viewModels: What does "by"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

Can someone explain what "by" does here?

```
val viewModel by viewModels<ProductsVM>()
```

Respectively how this code works? What happens there?

Comment: It is a [delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `by` is used for property delegation. When you declare a property with `by`, you call the getter and setter of the property to the object.

`viewModels` it's part of the Architecture Components in the Jetpack library. `viewModels` is a property used in  **MVVM** (Model-View-ViewModel) architecture used for activities or fragments to save or create.

```
val viewModel by viewModels<ProductsVM>()
```

> `viewModel` is a property in activity or fragment, and its delegated to the `viewModels` of `ProductsVM`. The line gets the `ProductsVM` `ViewModel` associated with the scope. If the `ViewModel` already exists, it will be returned, otherwise, it will be created.

Using `viewModel by viewModels<ProductsVM>()` handles the `viewModel` to the `viewModels` for proper creation and retention of the associated `ProductsVM` `ViewModel`.